# Selecting all rows in a table which distinct key

Tags: mysql

I want to only retrieve the table rows where productId is `DISTINCT`

So for this case, I want to retrieve:

```
 productID| name | price | ...
     1    |  ... |  ...  | ...
     2    |  ... |  ...  | ...
     3    |  ... |  ...  | ...
```

filtering out the repeated `productID`

[image]

What I have tried - `Product` is the table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `productId`  FROM `Product`

SELECT * 
FROM `Product` 
WHERE DISTINCT `productId`
```

Both of these don't work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What RDBMS is this for?

Comment: @marc_s this is mysql together with phpmyadmin

Comment: Your rows which you tell about like they're duplicates differs in some columns values (productindex, size). If you want to collapse those rows into one row then you must decide and completely define what one value from all possible ones must be returned in such column(s), then use GROUP BY with according expression for these columns. Or maybe the best way is to remove these columns from the output at all (do you need in them really?), in this case you may use DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join on a subquery which returns ids with their minimum product index, the subquery uses `group by` to get `productIds` as a "distinct" value and filter with `having` and the aggregate function `MIN` and get the record with the minimum productindex (ie: the first record with that productId)

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Product as `p`
inner join
(
   select `productId`, MIN(`productindex`) as `productindex`
   from Product
   group by `productId`
   having MIN(`productindex`)
) as `x`
on `x`.`productId` = `p`.`productId` and `x`.`productindex` = `p`.`productindex`
```

Comment: Hi, i have edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: @Dugong98 Updated, to use `MIN` on the `productindex` so that the first record of each product id is returned. This has been tested on sqlfiddle using MySQL 5.6